# Xbox 360 slim with HDMI and Audio adapter - No display

Tags: xbox-360, monitor

I have a new Slim 360 and because I'm connecting to my monitor (which has no speakers or sound output), I need to use the HDMI for video and a RCA audio adapter for sound.

[Here's the audio adapter I have](http://www.amazon.co.uk/Audio-Cable-Adapter-XBOX-Slim/dp/B005EDAFFS/ref=cm_cr_pr_product_top).

As far as I can tell this should work just fine right? Well for some reason as soon as I plug in the audio cable, the picture on the screen turns black.

Does anyone know why this might happen? This is the only way I can get sound so I really need to figure this out.

Comment: Ok, I've just been testing and it seems that when i plug in the audio adapter the whole console just resets...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The 'easiest' solution would be
 [here](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B000B6MLTG).  All in one solution to convert the audio to 3.5mm jack and a VGA (which your monitor should support - otherwise convert from there to DVI).

Comment: Yeah, I just went with this, I'm not sure why the other one doesn't work but I've ordered one of these from ebay and it should do the trick, thanks.

Comment: @HatInACat Feel free to up vote too if it helped :)

Answer (score 0):

I have the same setup, although I use optical audio, and it works just fine.

Microsoft [recommends](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/916158) you check these things:

1) Monitor is on hdmi input.

2) AV Cables are securely connected.  (I'd bet it's this one, the slim is pretty tight in there, and I could see the audio adaptor pushing the hdmi cable out of place)

3) If your audio cable has an hdmi or composite selector, switch it to composite.  I don't think your connector does.

4) Reset the xbox display options.  Make sure the disc tray is empty.  Turn on the console.  Press and hold the right trigger and the Y button on the controller.

There are further support docs linked from there if none of that fixes your issue.

Answer (score 0):

I know this question is old, but I stumbled upon it while experiencing this problem myself. This issue occurs when your system has Display Discovery enabled.

Go to Settings > Console Settings > Display Discovery and switch to 'Disabled'

This will allow you to use HDMI with RCA audio. You will have to manually input your monitor resolution in settings.